# Erro "No such file or directory " mas o arquivo é guardado no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, upload, imagem, if

Estou com o seguinte problema: quando submeto um formulário que contem fotografias aparece o erro descrito no titulo. se carregar so uma foto ja nao aparece. mas mesmo dando erro ele esta a guardar as imagens no banco. alguem sabe me dizer a origem deste erro? 
código do upload:

**UPLOAD IMAGENS**

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    // INFO DAS IMAGENS
    $file=$_FILES['img'];
    $numfile=count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PAsta para onde vão os arquivos
    $folder='fotografias';

    //tipos de ficheiros
    $extensoes= array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
    $maxsize=1024*1024*5;

    //mensagens
    $msg=array();
    $errormsg=array(
        1=> 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini',
        2=> 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
        3=> 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
        4=> 'Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.'
        );

    if ($numfile<=0)
        echo "Selecione pelo menos uma imagem!";
    else{
        for ($i=0; $i < $numfile; $i++) { 
            $name =$file['name'][$i];
            $type =$file['type'][$i];
            $size =$file['size'][$i];
            $error=$file['error'][$i];
            $tmp  =$file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao=@end(explode('.',$name));
            $novonome[$i]=microtime().".$extensao";

            if($error !=0)
                $msg[]="<b>$name:</b>".$errormsg[$error];
            else if (!in_array($type, $extensoes))
                $msg[]="<b>$name:</b> Erro! Imagem nao suportada!";
            else if ($size>$maxsize)
                $msg[]="<b>$name:</b> Erro! Imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5Mb!";
            else{

                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novonome[$i]))
                    $msg[]="<b>$name:</b> Upload realizado com sucesso";

                else
                    $msg[]="<b>$name:</b> Ocorreu um erro!";

            }  



            }

    }


}


$um=$novonome[0];
$dois=$novonome[1];
$tres=$novonome[2];
$quatro=$novonome[3];
$cinco=$novonome[4];
```

**Função inserir**

```
inserir(array("categoria","marca","modelo","ano","horas","img1","img2","img3","img4","img5"), array($categoria,$marca,$modelo,$ano,$horas,$um,$dois,$tres,$quatro,$cinco),"artigos");
```

Surgem dois erros:

**Erro 1**

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(fotografias/0.95092900 1449161528.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\dtcr\admin\proc_inserir.php on line 65

**Erro2**

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\wamp\tmp\php6409.tmp' to 'fotografias/0.95092900 1449161528.jpg'
>   in C:\wamp\www\dtcr\admin\proc_inserir.php on line 65

A linha 65 é aquela que contem o seguinte código:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novonome[$i]))
```

Comment: Tente usar caminhos absolutos no upload. Como `C:\fotografias\caminho\do\arquivo.jpg`

Comment: Coloca uma barra `/` em frente de `fotografias` e diga o que retornou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca o caminho completo de onde a imagem será salva. no seu caso está salvando para 'fotografias/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'

tente adicionar para a pasta ser: 'c:/.../.../.../fotografias/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg'

alterando a linha

```
$folder='c:/teste/pasta/fotografias';
```

Comment: mas eu nao sei o nome da foto...ele gera automaticamente o nome da foto.....
reparei agora que ele guarda o nome no banco mas nao move a foto para a pasta!

Comment: mas você sabe onde está a pasta que será salva. :) edite a linha onde está $folder e coloque o caminho completo da PASTA* :)

Comment: ja vou experimentar. mas o que é estranho é que ja estou a desenvolver isto ha algum tempo e estava a funcionar na perfeição

Comment: Repare no erro: Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php6409.tmp' to 'fotografias/0.95092900 1449161528.jpg' ele preencheu o caminho completo para a imagem temporária, mas no endereço de destino não tem o caminho completo. Tente ai e caso ocorra erro é só falar.

Comment: REsolvido! tentei e funcionou. pensei melhor e de facto eu tinha movido o ficheiro  de pasta e nao tinha atualizado ali! Obrigado!